# ¿Cómo evitar acceso a una carpeta, sin importar su ruta, con .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2, mod-rewrite

**Contexto:** Apache 2.4.37

**Problema:** Tengo una carpeta llamada *alfa* en cierta ruta (digamos /var/www/html/alfa), y tengo otra carpeta llamada igual *alfa* en otra ruta (digamos /var/www/html/otra/ruta/alfa). En resumen, tengo muchas carpetas llamadas igual (*alfa*) en distintas ubicaciones dentro de mi sitio web. ¿Cómo bloquear acceso a todas las carpetas *alfa* sin importar en qué ruta se encuentren?

**Qué he intentado.**

Sin éxito he intentado esto:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(alfa|beta) - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

Lo siguiente funciona, pero tengo que poner la ruta completa a la carpeta, y eso es justo lo que quiero evitar:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/ruta/a/la/carpeta/alfa($|/)#">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</If>
```

Comment: ¿Las carpetas se crean automáticamente? ¿Por qué no quieres el acceso a las carpetas? una forma fácil de evitar que alguien vea lo que hay en X carpeta es colocar un `index.php` y un `index.html` vacíos, eso no permite ver el árbol de archivos de la carpeta en cuestión. Hasta puedes poner un mensaje personalizado en cada una. Una vez lo hice para los perfiles de los empleados de un sistema y nunca tuve problemas y eso no te va a generar mayor peso en tu web.

Comment: Hola OCHOA. No me sirve lo de poner index.html, porque en teoría la gente interna sabe qué hay en esas carpetas.

Answer (score 0):

Hola puedes intentar con lo siguiente

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?alfa(/.*)?$ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

la expresion regular

```
^(.*/)?alfa(/.*)?$
```

debería cumplir con tus requerimientos es decir, denegar el acceso a cualquier nivel de ruta que contenga la palabra alfa como: /alfa/, /beta/alfa, etc

mientras que las flags

```
[F,L]
```

la F enviara un respuesta HTTP 403 (Forbidden) en caso de coincidir con la expresion regular

la L se utiliza para indicar que es la ultima regla aplicable, para evitar que otras reglas puedan intervenir sobre esta.